# Different behaviors between XmlDocument.LoadXml and XDocument.Parse

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Our project has been converted to use XDocument from XmlDocument few days ago, but we found a strange behavior while processing XML entity in attribute value with XDocument.Parse, the sample code as following:

1. The XML string:

   string xml = @"<char symbol=""&#x0;"">";
2. The XmlDocument.LoadXml code and result:

   ```
       XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
       xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
       Console.WriteLine(xmlDocument.OuterXml);
   ```

   Result:

   <char symbol="&#x0;" />
3. The XDocument.Parse code and exception:

   ```
       XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
       Console.WriteLine(xDocument.ToString());
   ```

   Exception:

   A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
   **'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 18.**
      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Int32 pos, String res, String[] args)
      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseNumericCharRefInline(Int32 startPos, Boolean expand, StringBuilder internalSubsetBuilder, Int32& charCount, EntityType& entityType)
      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseNumericCharRef(Boolean expand, StringBuilder internalSubsetBuilder, EntityType& entityType)
      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleEntityReference(Boolean isInAttributeValue, EntityExpandType expandType, Int32& charRefEndPos)
      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributeValueSlow(Int32 curPos, Char quoteChar, NodeData attr)
      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
      at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
      at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text, LoadOptions options)
      at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text)

It seems that the "&#x0;" is an invalid character, so we change the value to a valid character such as "&#x60;" then both methods worked well.

Is there any way to change the XDocument.Parse behavior to ignore the invalid character in attribute like XmlDocument.LoadXml does?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this arctice](http://seattlesoftware.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/hexadecimal-value-0-is-an-invalid-character/) the value � is actually invalid. I've experienced myself that the XDocument class follows the XML standard much stricter than XmlDocument (which I think is a good thing).

Read the article, they give suggestions how to get around that error.